# Populate a Kendo dialog with partial view

Tags: kendo-ui, dialog, partial-views

I have a `kendo dialog` which I want to populate with a `partial view` but it's sort of not working.
I want to populate the dialog with the click of a button, so here's my code so far

```
<div id="dialog"></div>

function showDetails(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

        var dialog = $("#dialog");

        console.log("objId", dataItem.OBJECTID1)
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SavePartial", "SettlementContract")',
            data: {
                id: dataItem.OBJECTID1
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    dialog.html(result);
                    dialog.data("kendoDialog").open();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I tried removing the `if` condition inside the `success`, just in case but it's not working either. It returns the partial view, but not inside the `kendo dialog`, the dialog doesn't even open. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see the partial on the page? Where in your code do you instantiate the dialog widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do this in our application and this is how we have set it up (I updated it to use your controller/actions/ids) - this is using the ASP.NET Core MVC wrappers:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Window()
        .Name("dialog")
        .Content("loading...")
        .Draggable()
        .Actions(actions => actions.Maximize().Close())
        .Resizable()
        .Modal(true)
        .Visible(false)
        .Events(e => e.Refresh("onDialogWindowRefresh"))
    )


<script>
  function showDetails(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

    let win = $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow");

    win.refresh({
        url: "/SettlementContract/SavePartial/",
        data: {
            id: dataItem.OBJECTID1
        }
    });
  }

  function onDialogWindowRefresh(e) {
    e.sender.center().open();
  }
</script>
```